# "one" in "one too many"

Tags: grammar, modifiers, structure

The phrase "have one too many" means "be slightly drunk."
But I am curious about the structure of "one too many."
Specifically, what kind of role does "one" play in the phrase?

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic phrase isn't "be one too many" it's **["have one too many."](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/have_one_too_many)**

**One too many** is an adjectival phrase that, in the idiom, modifies an implied noun at the end of the sentence.

> He's had one too many *[drinks]*.

We see it as an adjectival phrase with a stated noun when it's not used in the idiom.

> She broke her curfew **one too many times**, and her parents grounded her.
>
> He took **one too many chances**, and wound up breaking his leg in an accident.

Comment: What kind of role does "one" play in the phrases?

Comment: @Apollyon It's the adjective in the adjectival phrase.

Comment: "many" is the adjective, but is "one" really an adjective as well?

Comment: @Apollyon Yes. Numbers are often adjectives. By analogy: "He had _one_ drink."  "She broke curfew _three_ times."

Comment: "one" in "one too many (drinks) is more like an adverb indicating the extent of something. Compare "He is seven feet tall." 'seven feet" indicates the extent of his tallness. Another example: The bill is two months overdue.

Comment: @Apollyon When I was taught as a child, numbers were classified with adjectives and I was explicitly taught that cardinal numbers were never adverbs. From some looking around [Inline Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner#Description), I suppose the label for _one_, and also for _many_ would be "determiner" and specifically "quantifier." Whether you class that with adjectives or adverbs or as its own separate category is up for some debate--I think your argument that it's functioning adverbially has some merit. That said, the clause as a whole is adjectival.

Comment: @Apollyon [*One too many*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/one%20too) is an *idiom* that means "too many drinks." As any idiom, it acts as a single syntactical unit. In the complete sentence *he had [one too many]*, where no noun follows it, the idiom functions *only* as a noun phrase. But if a noun is added after it, then while the entire thing is still a noun phrase, *one too many* acts as an adjectival phrase in just the same way that *red* does in *he had a red ball*. If you have to analyze it further, *too* is an adverb—so *one* would also act adverbially as a further modifier.

Comment: @Katy "One" can also be a pronominal, i.e., an NP occupying the same structural position as "two months," "one inch," for instance.